# Windows 10 IoT (ARM) - RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

We have the following configuration :

- a Linux box acting as a USB Slave (RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget)
- a Windows 10 IoT (ARM) device acting as USB Host

When slave is connected to host, Windows IoT detect it but it appears as "USB Serial Device" and no new network adapter is available.

When slave is connected to a Windows 10 Pro, it works. 
Host/Slave can successfully communicate via Ethernet.

So my questions are :

- Does Windows IoT support RNDIS? (I was no able to find an official
  answer on the web)
- Do RNDIS driver exists for Windows IoT (ARM)?
- Did someone already tried what we are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry but I was not able to put "Hi,..." at the begining of my post

Comment: No need to apologize. Salutations are considered as clutter and should be omitted and are likely to get edited out. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/143302)

Comment: Please refer to the topic on MSDN forum(https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/78e473b4-dc36-4813-acb7-51dbee899176/rndis-ethernet-gadget?forum=WindowsIoT).

Comment: Thanks to Michael for his clear answer.